# Using variable across forms

Tags: winforms, variables

I have a string variable SuppCode which I assign in Form1. I want to use this variable in a Switch statement on Form2. I've tried using `public string SuppCode;` but I still get a `The name 'Switch' does not exist in the current context error` in the switch. What is it I need to change to allow me to use SuppCode Form2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is Form1 Owner of Form2? I mean, did you use instanceOfForm2.Show(instanceOfForm1); or instanceOfForm2.ShowDialog(instanceOfForm1); to show Form2? If it is, you can do:

```
 string s = ((Form1)this.Owner).SuppCode;
```

to access your variable from Form2

**EDIT:**
Your form has set owner when it was shown using methods:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Form2 form2 = new Form2()
form2.Show(form1);
//or
form2.ShowDialog(form1);
```

then form2 has Owner property set to form1.

You can also create your own property in Form2 to reference your form1.

```
class Form2
{
  public Form1 MyFormRef{get;set;}

  public Form2(){/*...*/}
  // or:
  public Form2(Form1 formref)
  {
     this.MyFormRef = formref;
  }

  private string getSuppCode()
  {
    if(this.MyFormRef!=null)return this.MyFormRef.SuppCode;
    else return null;
  }
}
```

use:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.MyFormRef = form1;
```

or:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Form2 form2 = new Form2(form1);
```

Comment: I'm just using frmReport f = new frmReport();  f.Show(); to show Form2 (named frmReport). When I try your code above, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.